# Storm bolt to verify if all tuples with a given field got processed

Tags: apache, apache-storm

I send multiple tuples to a bolt with parelleism count 8 and process,After that i'd like to emit id,index into a next Bolt that verifies if all tuples were processed and sends a notification. How can it be done? Does storm has an implementatino for it already?

Answer (score 0):

Storm already has a message guarantee system. You need to enable this in your bolts either by extending the BasicBolt and BasicSpout classes (which ack each tuple by default) or by explicitly calling the ack method of the OutputCollector class.

You then need to add logic to the fail and ack methods of your Spout. More details of the [Message Guarantee](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) API are here.

This system will let know if a tuple (emitted by the spout) fails to make it all the way through your topology. If you want to know about success through each step between executors you will either need custom logic in your bolts or alter the Acker implementation (not recommended).

However, if you are after guaranteed exactly one processing of each message then you should probably have a look at the [Trident](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.0/Trident-tutorial.html) library.